# Android custom fonts (nunito) not set properly in TextView

Tags: android, textview, custom-font, android-typeface

I am using custom fonts in my android `TextView.`

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "nunitomedium.ttf");
        txt2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        txt2.setTypeface(tf);
```

But padding between lines are not properly show.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:text="You can send emergency blast to friends and family whenever you feel uncomfortable. Once activated, you will be able to send an emergency blast to your safety network within seconds with the pressing of one button."
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
```

Here is my output :

[image]

I also tried with following code :

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

but still same issue. Not sure but I also tried to use `justifyTextView` from [Here](https://github.com/ufo22940268/android-justifiedtextview) but same issue. Does anybody faced same issue before?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

If i use   `android:lineSpacingExtra` 1st line have more space then other lines. Here is my code and output.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_5sdp" <<<<<<<
        android:text="You can send emergency blast to friends and family whenever you feel uncomfortable. Once activated, you will be able to send an emergency blast to your safety network within seconds with the pressing of one button."
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
```

[image]

Comment: share your ttf file also @Hardik Joshi

Comment: Hardik Joshi I am using samsung device, in that textview showing properly.

Comment: for me it looks like some problem with the font

Comment: @Ankita Here is my font file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/l899750xmb0krp1/nunitomedium.ttf?dl=0

Comment: @Lingeshwaran Hmm it seems device specific issues?

Comment: @VladMatvienko and HardikJoshi which device you are using?

Comment: @Lingeshwaran I am using Redmi note 3 (Android 6.0.1)

Comment: @HardikJoshi I am not able to get your ttf file ...

Comment: @Lingeshwaran, I've not tested the font, but I have a bunch of devices here (like 30, for testing my work). If needed I can make a test ap, and check on some of them.

Comment: @Ankita you mean not able to download font from dropbox link?

Comment: Yes , Actually i want to make a test on this ttf file so that can know what exactly wrong with your code.  @HardikJoshi

Comment: @VladMatvienko can you please download font and quickly create textview and test? It will take hardly 10 mins. And it will really helpful for me.

Comment: @Lingeshwaran Thanks for your support sir

Comment: @Ankita please try from here : https://files.fm/u/8g5nrgq2

Comment: @HardikJoshi, sure, doing

Comment: @HardikJoshi, OK, just tested on the OnePlus One with Android 6, and confirm the problem - first line spacing is OK, and all others have no spacing.

Comment: @HardikJoshi I have tested and resolved your issue. And posted the answer check it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thanks.

Comment: @Ankita ok let me check and test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the party on this - we had exactly the same issue, was fixed completely by replacing the .ttf font file with the latest from Google Fonts - there's a bad early version of this font doing the rounds. Don't forget to remove any `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` fudges you've put in place int he meanwhile.

Comment: Hey @Fisk thanks for reply. Can you share font file as well if possible? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for help @Fisk. You did it. I was working on this issue from past. I keep it with default fonts. but now i am also using nunito fonts in my app. Thank you brother. Happy codding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add linespacingMultiplier in your XML

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_font"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:text="You can send emergency blast to friends and family whenever you feel uncomfortable. Once activated, you will be able to send an emergency blast to your safety network within seconds with the pressing of one button."
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="3"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />
```

Or

Add these line in your code:-

```
 mTextViewFont=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_font);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "nunitomedium.ttf");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mTextViewFont.setLineSpacing((float) 5.5,(float) 1.2);
        }
        mTextViewFont.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: still the first line spacing is much larger that all other lines. Themes as a bug in a font itself

Comment: Agree with @VladMatvienko still 1st line has spacing much larger than all other lines

Comment: There was issue in the font file that is because of the site from where you downloaded it. I download the  file from http://www.dafontfree.net/download-nunito-f92263.htm   and then replace your file from asset folder. @HardikJoshi

Comment: I have shared the answer with the output(screenshot) @HardikJoshi

Answer (score 0):

There was issue in the font file that is because of the site from where you downloaded it. I download the file from

dafontfree.net/download-nunito-f92263.htm

and then replace your file from asset folder.

and this is the output of it.

[image]

Comment: Ok Let me check and will let you know.

Comment: Hello @Ankita, unfortunately this is not working in my end. Are you using emulator? OR This same output display in real device?

Comment: I am using emulator. I run your code on the same emulator but it was not showing properly. But when i replce the ttf file it is working fine. @HardikJoshi

Comment: Please check my code. Is it same? https://www.pastiebin.com/591eb3a208cb2

Comment: Did You download the ttf file from the link which i given to you?

Comment: If you are using the ttf file from the new link. Then you don't need to change your code(XML or java class). It will work fine after replacing the ttf file from asset folder. @HardikJoshi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144636/discussion-between-ankita-and-hardik-joshi).